# Passing arguments from CMD in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have got below Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/akamai
WORKDIR /usr/src/akamai

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/akamai/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/akamai

#EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "src/akamai-client.js", "purge", "https://www.example.com/main.css"]
```

Below is the command which I run from CMD after the docker image build

```
docker run -it "akamaiapi" //It executes the CMD command as given in above Dockerfile.
```

CMD ["node", "src/akamai-client.js", **"purge"**, **"https://www.example.com/main.css"**] //I want these two arguments directly passed from docker command instead hard-coded in Dockerfile, so my Docker run commands could be like these:

```
docker run -it "akamaiapi" queue
docker run -it "akamaiapi" purge "https://www.example.com/main.css"
docker run -it "akamaiapi" purge-status "b9f80d960602b9f80d960602b9f80d960602"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that through a [combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile).

- The [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) specifies a command that will always be executed when the container starts.
- The [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) specifies arguments that will be fed to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

So, with `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:boron
...

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "src/akamai-client.js"]

CMD ["purge", "https://www.example.com/main.css"]
```

The default behavior of a running container:

```
docker run -it akamaiapi
```

would be like command :

```
node src/akamai-client.js purge "https://www.example.com/main.css"
```

And if you do :

```
docker run -it akamaiapi queue
```

The underlying execution in the container would be like:

```
node src/akamai-client.js queue
```