# Docker starting container process caused "exec: \"arg\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Tags: bash, docker

My task is to create `Dockerfile` such that it works the following way:

`docker build -t test .`
Returns `Image named test successfully created`

`docker run --rm test`
Returns `Hello world!`

`docker run --rm test Universe`
Returns `Hello Universe!`

What I have so far:
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

LABEL maintainer="trthhrtz"

CMD if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then echo "Hello world!"; else echo "Hello " + $@ + "!"; fi
```

It does not work in case of input arguments, the error is:
`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"Universe\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

Comment: You had selected the right answer before. What has changed since then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to:

- define an entrypoint script `entrypoint.sh` with your command logic scripted in it.
- [`COPY` that file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in your Dockerfile
- leave `CMD` undefined

That way, any additional parameter to your `docker run -it --rm myImage arg1 arg2 ...` command will be passed to the bash entrypoint.sh script, which will interpret `$@` correctly, as illustrated in "[What does `set -e` and `exec "$@"` do for docker entrypoint scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39082768/6309)".
See "[Passing arguments from CMD in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280482/6309)" for more.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a correct order of arguments when you do `docker command`.

For example:

`docker run --name test-ubuntu -it d37f4165b5d2 bash`
instead of
`docker run --name test-ubuntu d37f4165b5d2 -it bash`